# How to Prevent Specific links such as "?a=page" from opening

Tags: .htaccess, smarty

I have a website which uses "Smarty Engine" and "?a=link" linking method (i don't know what this linking method is called)

I've already used RewriteEngine in .htaccess to use .php links such as home.php instead of ?a=home

**but how can i prevent ?a=home from opening? so the page can only opened with home.php link**

Edit: for example Login page is **?a=login** , i've used these lines to open it as **login.php**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/*login.php$   ./?a=login [L]
```

but i also need to **disable ?a=login**, so users can only open login page with "login.php"

Comment: Hard to fully understand the question, but it seems you want to map to `home.php` all URLs with queries like `?a=link` or `?a=home`. ¿Is that right? Some examples always help.

Comment: thank you for your reply, my script uses link such as ?a=home and ?a=contact , i want it to load only as home.php and contact.php which i've already defined in .htaccess , but i dont want any user to be able to open home.php with ?a=home link (i want to disable ?a=XXX links from .htaccess)

Comment: ¿How is your htaccess file? As far as I understand what you want is to get rid of the queries, period, and that might be done in htaccess so it is important to know it.

Comment: i just added this to the question, yes i want to get rid of **?a=page** links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your example, all you have to do is something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$   $1? [L]
```

The final `?` removes any query

Comment: Sure. Put this condition: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !QueryToKeep` That way the rule will skip all queries like `QueryToKeep`

Comment: thank you my awesome friend, i tried voting again but failed, i wish i could vote more :D thanks again